# How to get the -real- last character typed in input with maxlength?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know which character the user is typing into an input:

I have an input:

```
  <input maxlength="20"/>
```

and a script that returns the last typed char:

```
var eingabe;
$('form').on('keypress', function(event) {

    /// if no whitespace:
    if (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0) {
    eingabe = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    $('#eingabe').html("<div>Eingabe : "+ eingabe +"</div>");
   }
});
```

My question is:
because my input has a maxlength attribute, the last typed character on the keyboard is sometimes not the last -real- typed character into the input because the input is "full". How can I get the last character typed into the input?

Comment: You want the last-typed-character or the last-character from the `<input>` element's value? It appears those two things are not the same.

Comment: Why is `keypress` event attached to `form` element and not `input` element?

Comment: I want the last-typed character from the `input` that appears in the `input`.

Comment: 1. What if the last typed character is a combined character by pressing [^] + [a] = [â] - do you want to get a or â? 2. What if the user removes text via backspace, do you want to count that as a character, too? 3. What if the user pastes text into the input, does this count as "typing characters"?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but it must work...

Set onkeypress= or onkeydown= on the Input element and store the key value in a LastChr variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to call a function if the user types a specific character into my input field. I solved it with the following:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    // Get cursor position
    var start = this.selectionStart;

    // Get last typed character
    var lastChar = String.fromCharCode(this.value.charCodeAt(start - 1));

    if(lastChar === '[YOURCHARHERE]') {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Please keep in mind, that 'input' is only supported down to IE8, but if you don't care about a proprietary browser, you should be fine. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, use the value of the input element to get the last character like `$('#input_field').val().substr($('#input_field').val().length - 1)` or use your best coding skill to accomplish something similar without accessing the field twice, wink wink.

Comment: Thanks, i dont want to get the last character in the input (at the end of the string) but the last typed character that could be anywhere in the input

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup instead:

```
$('form').on('keyup', function(event) {

    var cursorPos = event.target.selectionStart;       
    var lastTypedChar = elem.target.value[cursorPos - 1];
  
});
```